# Generating random finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, pr.probability, finite-groups, open-problems, discrete-mathematics

I would like a method to efficiently generate a random finite group of a given order $n$.
If there are $g(n)$ non-isomorphic groups of order $n$,
ideally each group would occur with probability $1/g(n)$.
So if $n=64$, each of the $267$ groups would be generated with equal probability.
($g(n)$ is [A000001](http://oeis.org/A000001) in OEIS.)
Groups of order $n=2^k$ would be of special interest.

This is far from my expertise, and my searches must be using the wrong terminology,
because I have not found such methods. I'd appreciate pointers—Thanks!

***Addendum***. The comments indicate that
this appears to be an open problem, with little chance of resolution in the
near future. Now so tagged.

Comment: You may want to weight groups by their automorphism groups.  That is, if $a(G)$ denotes $1/\#\text{Aut}(G)$, and $b(n)$ is the sum of $a(G)$ over all groups $G$ of order $n$, then have an order-$n$ group $G$ occur with probability $a(G)/b(n)$.  This is the philosophy behind the Cohen-Lenstra heuristics.  For instance, see Qiaochu Yuan's answer to [mathoverflow.146861](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/146861/cohen-lenstra-heuristics-reference).

Comment: This sounds very pessimistic, but I would be very surprised if there were any reasonably accurate way of doing that except in cases where it is possible to produce a complete list of all groups of order $n$. It would be challenging to come up with any plausible ideas for this for groups of order a power of $2$, and even if you could do so, the results would be dependent on unproved conjectures that "almost all" such groups are $2$-step nilpotent with elementary abelian layers.

Comment: When I was a student, I thought about the problem of generating a random group in search of an improvement
of the Elliptic Curves Method (ECM) for factoring integers. The idea was that since
most finite groups are 2-groups, in particular one would almost always hit a group
with smooth order, and hence under reasonable circumstances obtain a factorization
almost instantly -- in contrast to ECM, which uses abelian groups only.
However, thinking a bit more about the issue, I realized the problems with feasibility ... .

Comment: As other have said, getting a uniform distribution on groups of order $n$ looks unlikely. Most groups of order $n$ are nilpotent, and most nilpotent ones have class at most $2$- these statements can be made reasonably precise.

Comment: This is related in spirit :) http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36735/enumeration-and-random-selection

Answer (score 5):

Are you running computer experiments to verify conjectures?  If so, the GAP SmallGroups library will give you exactly what you want up to $n = 1023$.

For example, the GAP commands

```
  n:=16;; G:=SmallGroup(n, Random(1,NumberSmallGroups(n)));
```

will return you a group chosen uniformly at random from the groups of order $n=16$.  Similar commands will work up to $n=1023$.  Indeed, it will work for also for all orders up to 2000 except for 1024, and for a considerable number of other orders.

You might also find the SmallGroups library web page to be helpful:
http://www.icm.tu-bs.de/ag_algebra/software/small/

It describes some of the methods involved.  If you're willing to select a group uniformly at random from a subcollection of all the groups of order $2^k$, then there are several papers on groups of order $2^k$ (for varying values of $k$) cited there.  Applying the methods therein might be enough for you, depending on what your specific needs are.

Comment: As there are $49487365422 \approx 5 \times 10^{10}$ groups of order $2^{10}$, it is reasonable for GAP to pass over $1024$!

Comment: Indeed, GAP even knows the count of these groups with NumberSmallGroups (but it won't let you get at the groups themselves via the SmallGroups library).

Comment: You may be interested also in `SmallGroupsInformation` function - it gives some more details how the groups of a given order are sorted in the library.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a stupid approach: Fill in a $n\times n$ multiplication table randomly, then check whether if satisfies the properties of a group.

(The hard part is associativity, apart from that we basically want our multiplication table to be a "magic square", maybe there's more efficient ways to uniformly generate magic squares, and then only check associativity).

Repeat until you actually get a group.

The end result should be uniformly distributed over all group multiplication tables, and since each group $G$ admits $(n-1)!/\left|Aut(G)\right|$ different multiplication tables, this leads to a distribution as described in Michael Zieve's comment.

This is of course far from practical, but illustrates that what you want is, in principle, possible.

Comment: Somewhat related: "[How many binary operations are associative?](http://mathoverflow.net/q/110211/6094)."

Comment: It's not clear to me that the procedure described above wouldn't favor certain isomorphism classes.  The original question wanted an equal chance at each isomorphism class of groups of order $n$.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't do that, as I explained. Rather, it weights the probability of each isomorphism class by the inverse of the order of the automorphism group, as I explained. (Which is apparently the more natural thing according to Michael Zieve's comment)